# What does AM in "AM Container" mean in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

In Hadoop, **what does AM in "AM Container" mean?**

There are many posts about the MapReduce error, "failed 2 times due to AM Container" ... "Exception from container-launch: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException" ... but none solve my problem (with my HBase job).

I'm a beginner and I'd like to start by knowing what AM stands for. I can't find anything on the web.

Comment: AM means Application Master, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/23396829/2759636

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another link from Hadoop which may help understanding the Application Master (as @nigge noted above).

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html

Comment: Thanks so much. And for other newbies, here's an actual page tying the two together: ApplicationMaster (AM): http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html